# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1. I had Ubuntu 12.04 installed with Windows 8.1 before, but it became corrupted so I decided to do a complete uninstall/reinstall with 14.04.

I'm booting from a USB stick that contains 14.04. It boots successfully to the USB stick, and I'm able to get to the installation screen for Ubuntu. I click on "Install Ubuntu", and connect to the Internet successfully. I meet all the requirements by the installer (enough hard drive space to install, connected to the internet, laptop is plugged in), so I click next to start installing. I select "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows", and click next. Then my laptop reboots and boots into Windows 8.1. There is no evidence that Ubuntu was installed.

I've tried it multiple times and every time it reboots at that step and automatically goes to Windows. I've also tried to quickly enter the boot order menu when it does reboot and boot again from my USB stick (also does not work). I don't have a blank CD at hand to make a boot CD/DVD, so I have to try and make my USB stick work.

Has anybody else experienced this problem? Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: Use the manual partitioning method http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: try to install first windows 8.1 AND AFTER ubuntu 14.04 try to use this program http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/
after this easy steapts you will find a working GRUB.

Comment: I wont prefer installing ubuntu 18.04. i also have dual boot but i installed ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows(now i use ubuntu 19.04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Have you backed up your data from the Windows system? Please do so before proceeding.

I manually repartitioned from the LiveUSB using Gparted first, and mine installed AOK.

Boot with the Ubuntu LiveUSB, and then launch Gparted from the System menu.*

Select and resize the Win8 NTFS partition, reducing it by at least 10GB. More is fine.

Create a new EXT4 (or whichever filesystem type you prefer) partition, leaving space for the swap file; the swap file should be sized equal to the chip memory, the RAM in your system.

Create a new swap partition as the last partition.

Click on the green check mark, confirm you want to make changes, and go make a hot beverage. Return later and the partitioning will be done. Then, proceed with the install from the LiveUSB.

### -

*If Gparted is not installed, open a terminal window and do

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 has some strict secure boot options enabled if I'm not wrong, maybe try to turn it off in bios and then try to instal ubuntu...check options in bios

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing, but I installed 22.04 alongside Windows 10 instead of what you did. There are many reasons why this might not work. Microsoft does everything it can to stop users from dual booting other operating systems alongside windows, so it might be very difficult. It could also be the fact that oyu are installing ubuntu 14.04. Just so you know, questions concerning any version older than 16.04 are off-topic. I suggest installing a newer version, like 18, 20 and 22 unless you absolutely need 14.04. I suggest running ubuntu on a virtual machine instead of on your computer, because that way, you can keep windows and also run ubuntu. [This site](https://www.unixmen.com/install-ubuntu-14-04-3-lts-virtualbo) may help you in doing that.

Comment: This is not off topic as it was asked 8 years ago. Ubuntu 18, 20 and 22 are versions of Ubuntu Core the only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit. All in all your answer is not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Ditch the usb and use [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to mount the iso directly to the C:/ drive.

Then be sure to install Ubuntu to the master boot record.

You may need to manually configure Ubuntu to boot windows after this.

There are a lot of community resources on this topic.